# Memcache Stats Not Outputting with Rails.cache.stats.... Rails/Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memcached

Good evening,

I'm trying to do some testing of the caching on my Rails app on Heroku, but Memcachier does not appear to be playing nicely...

I can pull values out of the cache no problem, but the stats doesn't give me any love...

```
=> "42:Quotes:2012-04-16"
irb(main):016:0> Rails.cache.exist?(str)
=> true
irb(main):017:0> Rails.cache.read(str)
=> {"VCE.TO"=>24.76, "XIU.TO"=>17.19, "EWC"=>27.44}
irb(main):018:0> Rails.cache.stats
=> {"mc1.ec2.memcachier.com:11211"=>{}}
```

Should there not be some data in the stats if I can pull information out of the cache?  I have the following in my gemfile:

```
gem 'dalli'
gem 'memcachier'
```

And the following in production.rb:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

Any help would be appreciated - I can post more detail as required!