# Rails.cache.stats gives only three values (not extensive stats)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am using Rails, Heroku and the Dalli gem.

If I type `Rails.cache.stats` in the Heroku console I get `{"mc2.ec2.memcachier.com:11211"=>{"cur_items"=>"408", "bytes"=>"8920696"}}` whereas everywhere I Google it and here on StackOverflow it seems like I should get extensive stats like [this one](https://gist.github.com/1169246).

Why can't I see the extended stats? It is very likely the same problems as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168399/memcache-stats-not-outputting-with-rails-cache-stats-rails-heroku) but I am not sure.

Comment: only difference: I use memcache, not memcachier and I actually have much more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the thing is, that you are using the memcachier plugin as a backend for the dalli-store.

the output of the `stats` command is not the regular stats that the `memcached` would give, but that of the plugin-provider.

have a look at the heroku docs (search for stats) for example data of what this should return: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier

Comment: Thanks, so I am not missing an argument or anything. I just can't see this. Is that correct? For what plugins is it possible to see that extensive data in that case? What are "most other" using in order to get that much stats?

Comment: @Christoffer once you login to heroku, you can have a web-view for your memcachier plugin that has slightly more info. i guess that you have all the information available once you are on a paid plan, but that is just a guess.

Comment: If you refer to the Memcachier analytics it gives you some info about how many keys are being used and the percentage used but nothing else. Thanks anyway.